# WPF - Redirect Trace.WriteLine to file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, logging

In WPF Project, into the `App.config` file I put this code:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="textListener" type="TestRUT2xx.Tools.Diagnostics.DateTimeTextWriterTraceListener, TestRUT2xx" initializeData="TestRUT2xx_logger.log"
      />
      <remove name="Default" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textListener" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

And this is the code of `DateTimeTextWriterTraceListener`:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestRUT2xx.Tools
{
    namespace Diagnostics
    {
        public class DateTimeTextWriterTraceListener : TextWriterTraceListener
        {
            public DateTimeTextWriterTraceListener(string fileName) : base(fileName) { }

            public override void Write(string message)
            {
                base.Write($"[{DateTime.Now:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}]: {message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why the timestamp is not logged? When I open the log file, there are all the `Trace.WriteLine()` but each line don't have the timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard of this class, probably pretty useful for diagnosing WPF issues.
I could imagine the tracing engine also or most often uses **TextWriterTraceListener.WriteLine**, so you should also override this method to be on the safe side.

```
namespace TestRUT2xx.Tools
{
    namespace Diagnostics
    {
        public class DateTimeTextWriterTraceListener : TextWriterTraceListener
        {
            public DateTimeTextWriterTraceListener(string fileName) : base(fileName) { }

            public override void Write(string message)
            {
                base.Write($"[{DateTime.Now:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}]: {message}");
            }

            public override void WriteLine(string message)
            {
                base.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}]: {message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```